# Why my design gets disappear when I use <TouchableWithoutFeedback>?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
      <View style={{flex:1}} >
      <ImageBackground
          source={require('../images/back02.png')}
          style={styles.bgscreen}
          onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
          >
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
          <Image
          style={styles.headImage}
          source={require('../images/login_img.png')} />
        <ImgBack navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ImageBackground>
        </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

If I remove `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` then everything is fine. Help me. Don't ask for the Child Component code. No need to know about that. Everything is fine there.

I am just having a problem with the `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`

I have imported `import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

for both platforms ios and android.

Comment: Try to add flex:1 to TouchableWithoutFeedback

Comment: which platform , android or ios ?

Comment: both. android and ios too !

Comment: @LeventeGabos your solution not working. Made no difference !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the import statement.
use

```
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
```

instead

```
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `style={{height: '100%'}}` to your `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component

Answer (score 0):

faced this problem before and imported it from react native not react native gesture handler or use button with transparent attribute  instead of touchable